# Updating Class/IL in Assembly

Tags: c#, .net

If I have an assembly which I would like to update a few files in what tool do I need in order to do this?

For example, in java one can decompress a jar file update the desired .class and recompress the jar.  How can I accomplish the equivalent in .NET?

Comment: An assembly doesn't contain any files, it is nothing like a Java jar.  Pretty unclear what you are trying to accomplish.  Maybe [this](http://www.bytecodeartist.net/2011/05/introduction-to-il-rewriting-with-cecil.html)

Answer (score 3):

ILMerge would be the easiest IMO.

Steps:

1. Create new assembly for extra code
2. Use ILMerge to merge the code with the primary assembly

[ILRepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack) is an alternative to ILMerge.

Ideally, though, you should just add the code to the primary project, and recompile, if possible.